# closing android application destroy broadcast receiver

Tags: android

In main activity in `onCreate` method I register `broadcastReciver` but when I close application I always get this error:

```
@429d47e0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
04-10 23:40:48.161: E/ActivityThread(20989):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:793)
04-10 23:40:48.161: E/ActivityThread(20989):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
04-10 23:40:48.161: E/ActivityThread(20989):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1274)
04-10 23:40:48.161: E/ActivityThread(20989):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1261)
04-10 23:40:48.161: E/ActivityThread(20989):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1255)
04-10 23:40:48.161: E/ActivityThread(20989):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
```

when I close application I don't want to unregister receiver. What can I do? I register receiver programatically.

Comment: what even you listen to?

Comment: Is't it self explanatory?

Comment: @pietmau it is? So tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I close application I don't want to unregister receiver

Then you should not be registering it via `registerReceiver()`. Register it in the manifest via a `<receiver>` element instead. Then, it is available whether or not your application is running.

Comment: this is one option but I want to register receiver when I click on ON button so not all the time.

Comment: @senzacionale: You still need to register the receiver in the manifest. You can use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to control whether or not it is active, based upon your button press.